# Can you tell unison-gtk NOT to auto-rescan when you open/change a profile?

Tags: gtk, unison

I want unison-gtk to do nothing when I change a profile. This way I can instead press <kbd>A</kbd> to *detect updates and proceed without waiting*.

This is important in case I need to go do something else and just comeback when it finishes rescanning and propagating changes. Without this, I am forced to wait until it finishes rescanning, press <kbd>A</kbd>, and wait again, which is very bad on huge syncs.

I can't find an option to do it. Is there something hidden? Some environment variable to set? Or will I have to fork and patch it?